# Export to Excel button getting invisible after loading Data in the Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using jquery Datatable on which I am populating some data from the data source. Before data is being populating in the Datatable I could see all the export buttons e.g export to Excel or Pdf etc. As soon as I populate Data on the Datatable the export buttons gets hide somehow and I am unable to figure out what is causing the issue. Any help with this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Below is JS which I am using.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#importPool').DataTable({
            //"dom": "Bfrtip",
            "dom": 'lBfrtip',

            //btext: 'Export',
            buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
            ]

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. Actually I needed the above piece of code after the ajax call back function for obvious reasons :)

```
"fnDrawCallback": function (data) {
                   if (data.json.data.length > 0) {
                            btnUpload.disabled = false; }
                                  },

                "dom": "Bfrtip",
                btext: 'Export',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'collection',
                        text: 'Export Reports',
                        buttons: [
                            'excel',
                            'csv',
                            'pdf'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
```